# Error while installing MiKTeX in windows7

Tags: miktex

I am trying to install MiKTeX 2.9 on my Windows 7 computer, I have been getting this error message:

```
The operation could not been completed for the following reasons
Permission denied path= C:\Program files\MikTex2.9\doc/bibtex/base/btxbst.doc
Details path= C:\Program files\MikTex2.9\doc/bibtex/base/btxbst.doc
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are the three lines you've posted the entirety of the error message, or was there more? Please advise.

Comment: yes all the three lines are from error message

Comment: And is that all you got? To me, this error message seems rather incomplete or truncated.

Comment: The operation could not been completed for the following reasons
Permission denied path= C:\Program files\MikTex2.9\doc/bibtex/base/btxbst.doc
Details path= C:\Program files\MikTex2.9\doc/bibtex/base/btxbst.doc

Comment: Please post the full error message in the *body* of your query, not in a comment.

Comment: Are you sure you run the installer with administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes with administrative privileges

Comment: Did you try to make the `basic` installation?

Comment: "Permission denied" normally means exactly what it says: something (virus protection or some setting in your OS or some group policy in your network) is denying miktex the right to write the file to C:\program files. If you don't need a multiuser installation you can try to install miktex in some other folder "only for you". You don't need admin rights to do this, simply use your normal user account. On my system miktex is in D:\miktex